# Closing OPEN-RECURSIVE and DICTIONARY LOOKUP CURSOR CACHED cursors through an SQLJ file

Tags: caching, cursor, recursive-query, sqlj

We have an SQLJ file where we specified an iterator to fetch multiple records from a table. Currently we are trying to upload 300 records from an intermediate table to the actual table by fetching 50 records out of the total 300 records at a time.

The issue we are facing is that, every fetch is creating 50 iterators out of which 1 cursor is DICTIONARY LOOKUP CURSOR CACHED and 49 are OPEN-RECURSIVE. After we have looped through the iterator, we have a close call in finally block, but this closes one one cursor and we are left with 48 OPEN-RECURSIVE cursors and 1 DICTIONARY LOOKUP CURSOR CACHED. I'd like to know if there is any specific way to close all these. I have tried to look in web but haven't really come across much regarding this scenario.

```
    #sql public static iterator UploadDetailsList(BigDecimal ID, String FUNCTION_ID,String TABLE_NAME)
#sql public static iterator UploadDetailsListAnother(BigDecimal ID, String FUNCTION_ID,String TABLE_NAME)
public List<UploadDto> getRecords(UploadDto newDto,int fromRowNo){
    //fromRowNo is sent as 0
    int maxResults=50;
    int toRowNum= fromRowNo + maxResults;
    UploadDetailsList uploadDetailsList=null;
    UploadDetailsListAnother uploadDetailsListAnother=null;
    try{
        #sql  uploadDetailsList = {SELECT ID,FUNCTION_ID,TABLE_NAME FROM UPLOAD_TABLE WHERE  STATUS= 'U' AND ROWNUM BETWEEN :fromRowNo AND :toRowNum};
        while(uploadDetailsList.next()){
            //populate details to Dto object
           try{
                #sql  uploadDetailsListAnother = {SELECT ID,FUNCTION_ID,TABLE_NAME FROM UPLOAD_TABLE WHERE  STATUS= 'U' AND ROWNUM BETWEEN :fromRowNo AND :toRowNum};
                while(uploadDetailsListAnother.next()){
                    //populate details to Dto object
                }
           }
            catch(Exception e){
                //print error
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //print error
    }
    finally{
        try{
            dbg("Inside finally in List<UploadDto> getRecords(UploadDto newDto,int fromRowNo)");
            if(uploadDetailsList != null){
                dbg("Closing uploadDetailsList");
                uploadDetailsList.close();
            }
             if(uploadDetailsListAnother != null){
                dbg("Closing uploadDetailsListAnother");
                uploadDetailsListAnother.close();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //print error
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone let me know where i'm going wrong or is there anything i might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Found the silliest mistake i made. The 2nd iterator inside the 1st while loop should have been close then and there with a finally block after the try catch for that iterator. This worked for me. Leaving the question here in case someone else makes the same mistake.
Here is the code

```
#sql public static iterator UploadDetailsList(BigDecimal ID, String FUNCTION_ID,String TABLE_NAME)
#sql public static iterator UploadDetailsListAnother(BigDecimal ID, String FUNCTION_ID,String TABLE_NAME)
public List<UploadDto> getRecords(UploadDto newDto,int fromRowNo){
    //fromRowNo is sent as 0
    int maxResults=50;
    int toRowNum= fromRowNo + maxResults;
    UploadDetailsList uploadDetailsList=null;
    UploadDetailsListAnother uploadDetailsListAnother=null;
    try{
        #sql  uploadDetailsList = {SELECT ID,FUNCTION_ID,TABLE_NAME FROM UPLOAD_TABLE WHERE  STATUS= 'U' AND ROWNUM BETWEEN :fromRowNo AND :toRowNum};
        while(uploadDetailsList.next()){
            //populate details to Dto object
           try{
                #sql  uploadDetailsListAnother = {SELECT ID,FUNCTION_ID,TABLE_NAME FROM UPLOAD_TABLE WHERE  STATUS= 'U' AND ROWNUM BETWEEN :fromRowNo AND :toRowNum};
                while(uploadDetailsListAnother.next()){
                    //populate details to Dto object
                }
           }
            catch(Exception e){
                //print error
            }
            //moved the finally here with closing of the inner iterator
            finally{
                try{
                    if(uploadDetailsListAnother != null){
                        dbg("Closing uploadDetailsListAnother");
                        uploadDetailsListAnother.close();
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    //print error
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        //print error
    }
    finally{
        try{
            dbg("Inside finally in List<UploadDto> getRecords(UploadDto newDto,int fromRowNo)");
            if(uploadDetailsList != null){
                dbg("Closing uploadDetailsList");
                uploadDetailsList.close();
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            //print error
        }
    }
}
```